# linebreaks filter with mixed HTML \ plain text string

Tags: html, django, filter, line-breaks

I have a string like this:

```
Plain text with newlines.
But it also has some html.

<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like the lineabreaks filter to output an HTML like this:

```
<p>Plain text with newlines.<br/>
But it also has some html.</p>
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
</ul>
```

But what I get is:

```
<p>Plain text with newlines.<br/>
But it also has some html.</p>
<ul><br />
<li>first</li><br />
<li>second</li><br />
</ul>
```

Any idea to prevent HTML parts to be line-breaked, but still allow the filter to do its job on plain text parts?

EDIT - @Shang Wang: The real-world usage for this filter is a backend for writers who are familiar with HTML and prefer not to use a rich text editor, but would still like to avoid typing "<br />" or "<p>" everytime they need to go to a newline.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to emulate Drupal's "Filtered HTML" input filter, which is meant for editors who need a way to quickly write simple articles without using a WYSIWYG editor, but with the possibility to add more advanced HTML tags (like , , etc..) here and there.

Hope this helps to understand my goal, and sorry for my english.

EDIT 2 - @karison: I don't have a particular approach, yet. My current code is:

```
{{ myText | bleach | linebreaks }}
```

I'd like to avoid to write from scratch a custom filter just for this, so I don't have any code to show. As it's something that I've seen in Drupal and other CMS, I was hoping that there was some way to do it with the current linebreaks filter.

Comment: Mind posting what you're current approach?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think it's possible and it doesn't make much sense. You could have new lines in your html section as well:

```
<p>This is a
    multiple line text.
</p>
```

but they won't be shown as multiple lines when the browser is rendering them. Then what is the template filter suppose to do? I think the best option for you is to separate the text yourself in your views.

**Edit**:

First off I'm not aware of any such django template filter exists because your situation is too specific to make it a public template filter, also the requirement is complex and require a parser to distinguish between html and plain text.

Secondly, multi-line text is not rendered by inserting `<br/>` for each new line([w3school's doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)). Instead you use the tag `<pre></pre>` to wrap your paragraph. In theory, for each block of plain text you could wrap `<pre>` around it, then the new lines will be shown "as is".

Comment: I've edited my original post with more infos. The case you mention is something that shouldn't happen in my scenario, as the writer would have no reasons at all to use <p></p> explicitly if the filter takes care of it. So that newline inside <p> is probably a human error and I'm expecting the filter NOT to add the <br />.